# Look for conftest.py in custom location

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following directory structure in my directory

```
tests
|
|__A
|  |__test_1.py
|__B
|  |__test_2.py
|__C
|  |__test3.py
|__D
|  |__test4.py
|__test_setup
|  |__conftest.py
|__pytest.ini
```

so my pytest.ini looks like follows

`[pytest]
confcutdir = tests/test_setup/
rootdir = tests/test_setup`

SO my question here is I want pytest to look into tests/test_setup for conftest.py
One option is to keep conftest.py at tests directory level (that's not a good option)

when I try to run:

`py.test --multihost-config=test.yaml test_1.py -q -s`

it fails to load conftest.py which has a bunch of fixtures.

Am I doing it right or my pytest.ini is screwed up?

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

conftests are local plugins for certain directories

if you want to use them in a different fashion,
you need to create plugins and reference them as plugins you want to use

(plugins can be just python modules you name in local contests)

in general you should NEVER import a fixture

because each import site is considered a new fixture (even for session scope)

instead you should declare modules that contain fixtures